# XPages typeahead how to send value of a combo box filter to the server

Tags: javascript, combobox, xpages, client-side, typeahead

I have an XPage that has a simple search feature.
The simple search consists of a combo box denoting the name of the item containing the information to be searched for, and a text box entry field wherein the user can enter the value for which to search.

The "filter" combo box contains things like "RecordID" "Requestor", "Assignee", etc.

When the user selects a filter and types in a term for which to search and presses enter, a search is performed on the server and the results are returned correctly.   For example, if the user selects "RecordID" and types in "ABCD" and hits enter, then all resulting records are returned that have "ABCD" within the RecordID field.   If the user selects "Requestor" and types in "Joe Smith", then all the records which have "Joe Smith" in the Requestor field are returned.    This works great.

My problem is when I try to add type-ahead to the value field.  The typeahead is working, but only filters for the LAST SUBMITTED value of the combo box.   Example: If the user selects "RecordID" and the last search was performed using "RecordID", the the typeahead will properly filter for RecordID results as they type in information.  If the user changes the filter to "Requestor" and begins typing in a name, results are not returned.  If they hit enter and get results back based on Requestor, and then clear the value field and begin to type in another Requestor's name, the typeahead works fine.

I'm pretty sure the problem is due to me not knowing how to access the value of the combo-box during the typeahead event.  My code is below (with println statements to try and determine the value of the combo-box.  The .value property and the .getValue() method are both returning the PREVIOUSLY submitted value of the combo box.  The .getSubmittedValue() property is returning null.

```
<xp:comboBox
    id="simpleSearchFilter1"
    value="#{XSPrequestSearcher.simpleSearchFilter}">
    <xp:selectItems
        value="#{XSPrequestSearcher.simpleSearchChoices}" />
</xp:comboBox>

<xp:inputText
    id="simpleSearchValue1"
    value="#{XSPrequestSearcher.simpleSearchValue}">
    <xp:typeAhead
        mode="partial"
        valueMarkup="true"
        var="searchfor"
        minChars="3">
        <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:var obj = getComponent("simpleSearchFilter1");
var value = obj.value;
var gvalue = obj.getValue();
var svalue = obj.getSubmittedValue();

println("***********");
println("simpleSearchValue1.typeahead");
println("\t value: " + value);
println("\t gvalue: " + gvalue);
println("\t svalue: " + svalue);

XSPrequestSearcher.setSimpleSearchFilter(getComponent("simpleSearchFilter1").value);
XSPrequestSearcher.getTypeaheadChoicesSimple(searchfor); }]]></xp:this.valueList>
    </xp:typeAhead>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onchange"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="#{compositeData.partialRefreshTargetID}">
        <xp:this.script>
            <xp:executeClientScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[return !isBlank("#{id:simpleSearchValue1}");]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeClientScript>
        </xp:this.script>
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:XSPrequestSearcher.setSimpleSearchFilter(getComponent("simpleSearchFilter1").value);}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Is it possible to bind the simpleSearchFilter1 to a scoped variable, and reference the scoped variable?  Or, if it is bound to a java bean, then reference the bean instead of getComponent.  Don't know if this will make a difference but worth a try.

Comment: It is bound to a variable property on the Bean. I also tried it on a scoped variable.   The problem is that it doesn't update unless I set a submit for the on change event which I really don't want to do.

Comment: Was pretty sure you tried that.  Maybe try this, in the onClick event, have client-side code that writes the current value of the field back to the server using XSP.PartialRefreshPost and sets it to a scoped variable or somewhere you can access it.

Comment: The Problem is that if you do not send the selected item back to the Server your typeahead will never know wich item the user has selected. Therefore you will have to send the selection via Ajax to the Server and return the filtered items to the Client before the user starts typing in your search field. Use Serdars solution for a minimal onchange Event but im sure you will have to refresh the search field or at least the typeahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the value of your combobox, it does not submit its value to the server. Since the partial refresh within the typeahead works locally around your input component, it doesn't have a clue about the client-side value of the combobox.

So there are two options. First, you can submit the combobox value on each change by adding a simple eventHandler inside the combobox:

```
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onchange"
    submit="true"
    refreshMode="norefresh" 
    disableValidators="true">
</xp:eventHandler>
```

This will make a short AJAX call whenever the user changes its value. It doesn't need to refresh anything or validate fields at this situation.

**UPDATE:**

The above method will create UI lag and using this [snippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=typeahead-onstartoncomplete-event) does not work as you suggested in the comment. Because the partial refresh operation is an async operation, so when you start the typeahead, it does not wait for the partial refresh operation.

But modifying the snippet a little bit will work. The problem here is that searchValue does not mean anything for us without the searchFilter. Therefore, I have looked a way to submit both information simultaneously. That's possible via the same method with the snippet.

First, I have given an `id` for the `typeAhead`. This is important, especially if you want to use multiple typeAhead on the same page.

```
<xp:typeAhead
    id="simpleSearch"
    mode="partial"
..... other attributes ....
</xp:typeAhead>
```

Now we will inject some CSJS into the Ajax request, specifically for the typeahead ones.

```
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[ 
dojo.addOnLoad( function(){

/*** hijacking xhr request ***/
if( !dojo._xhr )
  dojo._xhr = dojo.xhr;

dojo.xhr = function(){
  try{
     var args = arguments[1];
     if( args['content'] ){
        var content = args['content'];
           if( content['$$ajaxmode'] ){
              if( content['$$ajaxmode'] == "typeahead" ){
                    // Paranoid check for multiple typeahead:
                  if(content['$$ajaxid'] == "#{id:simpleSearch}") {
                    var filterType=dojo.byId("#{id:simpleSearchFilter1}").value;
                    content['$$value']=filterType+":"+content['$$value'];
                  }
              }
         }
     }
  }catch(e){}
  dojo._xhr( arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2] );
}
});]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Here, we are basically checking every typeahead requests. If some typeahead is originated from our typeahead, we add the filter type in front of the submitted searchfor value. Therefore, our searchfor value will be changed. You need to change the typeAhead value list function accordingly:

```
var searchFilter=@Left(searchfor, ":");
var searchValue=@Right(searchfor, ":");
// Use searchFilter and searchValue to generate a value list.
```

One little note here. We are using Ajax injection. If our page is using a similar injection (e.g. standby dialog etc.), variable names like `dojo._xhr` should be revised carefully.

Comment: Using eventHandler causes lag in the UI.

Using snippet and partialRefreshPost() sort of works -AFTER the first typeahead returns.  Subsequent results are filtered.   

EX:  User sets filter to "Requestor" and types in "Joh" -the typeahead filter on the server is still "RecordID" and no match is found, empty string is returned to browser.    

If the user types "n", the server filter is now "Requestor" and matches to "John" are found.  The result typeahead is sent back to the browser ("John Bigbooté", "John O'Connor", "John Small Berries", "John Whorfin", "John Yaya", etc. )

Comment: I think I know the problem. Since the partial refresh is an async operation, it starts type-ahead before the submission is over. I'll think about a better solution for that.

Comment: @spanky762 I have added a hacky solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make your typeahead code work with any of your possible items on the combobox.  Using SSJS or Java you can build a HashMap of possible typeahead examples but looping through multiple collections.  It works really well.  We use this at the day job effectively.

I did a brief NotesIn9 on this in show 24:  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2011/02/11/notesin9-24-fancy-type-ahead-in-xpages/

In that show I have a type ahead that works if you type a persons last name OR the first name.  (That's not my best video but you get the concept)

so in your example you could have your typeahead that works against: RecordID OR Requestor OR any other choice.  Then if you really do want to know what was in the combobox you'll gain access to that on the submit.

Works really well....

Comment: While this answer does not really solve the problem of how to get the selected value from the combo box back to the server where it can be used to filter the results, it DOES allow me to get typeahead results (although unfiltered) and send them back to the browser client.  For that reason I am voting it up.