# XPages pager refresh issue

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a problem with a pager performing a partial refresh (since we have server side redirection rules, full refresh is not an option here). If I place the pager on the same page rather than in a custom control then it refresh the main panel. But if I place the pager in a custom control, then it only updates the repeat control, which means the pager control itself doesn't get refreshed. Here is a simple example to demonstrate the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:panel id="mainPanel">
        <xc:ccPager pagerFor="repeat1" id="myPager" />
        <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="3" var="row">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
return cars; }]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{row}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

And here is the code for the custom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true"
        id="pager1" for="#{compositeData.pagerFor}" partialExecute="false">
    </xp:pager>
</xp:view>
```

Any tips would be welcome. In this case the pager is simple, but I have a more complex pager and a pagesizes control with 45 lines of source code, so I would prefer to create a re-useable custom component if possible at all.

### UPDATE

My current pager custom control:

```
<div id="page-result" class="pagination pagination-small clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12 pagination clearfix">
        <div class="results form-inline left">
            <fieldset>
                <xp:pager id="pager1" alwaysCalculateLast="true"
                    for="#{compositeData.strPagerFor}" styleClass="pag-control"
                    partialRefresh="true" partialExecute="false">
                    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl1" type="FirstImage"
                        styleClass="firstPage" image="/PagerArrowhead2-L_d.png">
                    </xp:pagerControl>
                    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl2" type="PreviousImage"
                        styleClass="previousPage" image="/PagerArrowhead-L_d.png">
                    </xp:pagerControl>
                    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl5" type="Group"
                        currentStyleClass="active" styleClass="pages">
                    </xp:pagerControl>
                    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl3" type="NextImage"
                        styleClass="nextPage" image="/PagerArrowhead.png">
                    </xp:pagerControl>
                    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl4" type="LastImage"
                        styleClass="lastPage" image="/PagerArrowhead2.png">
                    </xp:pagerControl>
                </xp:pager>
                <label>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{compositeData.strLabelText}" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="results form-inline">
            <fieldset>
                <label> Results per page: </label>
                <xe:pagerSizes id="pagerSizes1" for="#{compositeData.strPagerFor}"
                    sizes="7|15|25|50|all" text="{0}" styleClass="resultPage"
                    partialRefresh="true" partialExecute="false"
                    refreshId="#{compositeData.strRefreshPanel}" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you specify the panel to update?

Comment: Did you consider placing the custom control into the header facet of the repeat control? It works in that way.

Comment: Thanks Serdar, in order to place it in the header and footer section of the repeat control, we will need to make major design changes, but it's a solution nonetheless, I will give it a go.

Comment: Steve, that's the problem with the pager control, you cannot specify a panel to update! But as I described in my example, if you place the pager on the xpage it will update the whole page.

Comment: Another solution is to implement a new component that inherits the repeat control (or its renderer). Just to grab paging event and do a self refresh. Maybe, even a custom renderer would be sufficient. Though, without actually seeing the code itself, it might be more difficult.

Comment: Just thought, did you consider injecting a client-side code into the pager event? you can inject yourself into xhr code and if it's a pager event, you might refresh the panel container. Just like in here: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control and also in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292840/xpages-typeahead-how-to-send-value-of-a-combo-box-filter-to-the-server/25302957#25302957

Comment: That sounds great Serdar, many thanks, I think I will give that a go in Domino 8.5.3. I will also update the question with my current pager code. Also any ideas on the pagerSizes control from the extension library? That control has no events whatsoever!!

Comment: Serdar, if you wish to post your comment as a answer, I would be happy to accept your answer for this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this problem before. I think it's because the view container cannot find the pager when it's in a separate custom control. I presume it's using something like getComponent, which can't navigate down into custom controls, so it can't locate the pager to update it.

Can you extract the code for your pagesizes control into a Java dataObject / bean / util or dataContext / SSJS library? Then reference it with one line of SSJS or EL?

The other option would be to use a plugin and build a component that extends the repeat control and adds the pager to the relevant header?

Tim Tripcony gave a great demo of a quick and dirty way of doing it http://www.notesin9.com/2012/04/04/notesin9-064-global-custom-controls-fixed/

Comment: Thanks Paul for some interesting ideas, so it's not a quick fix.